# Concatination of strings in treemap from the following code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hashmap, treemap

I'm using this way to call the class and object still can't figure out what is wrong in getting the concept right

```
public class MMTUtil{
    private static Map<String, String> domainDocumentationMap = null;

    static{
        domainDocumentationMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getDomainDocumentationMap() {
        return domainDocumentationMap;
    }

    public static void setDomainDocumentationMap(Map<String, String> domainDocumentationMap) {
        MMTUtil.domainDocumentationMap = domainDocumentationMap;
    }
```

How shall I use the `setDomainDocumentation` and `getDomainDocumentation` effectively with the code so that my `Treemap` has the following set of values

> (objectType + objectname,DocumentationLink)

```
public UMRResultObject insertDocumentation(UMRDocumentationDTO documentationDTO)
{
    Session session = UMRHibernateUtil.getUmrSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    documentationLink = null;
    objectName = null;
    objectType = null;

    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        dao.insertDocumentation(documentationDTO, session);

        MMTUtil.getDomainDocumentationMap().put(objectName.getDomainName()+objectType.getDomainType(),documentationLink.getDocumentationLink());
        tx.commit();
        ro.setSuccess(true);
        ro.getMessages().add("Record Inserted Successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please dont downvote, but help me understand what is happening in there

Comment: What is your intention ? Please explain in non-code way.

Comment: well the flow is this
users select the domianName and domainType and with that enter a String link to it domainName and combo are the composite key and that is needed to to be stored in the treeMap and that is what i'm trying to accomplish from my efforts (the UI part is in JSP)